# Google map not render with library vue2-google-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying render a map using google-maps with vue, I am using a webpackage for transpiler vue js, I have a file main.js this call to all the importations.

### file mains.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import { load } from 'vue2-google-maps'
load({
    key: 'my-api',
    v: '3.exp',
    installComponents: false
});

import App from './components/app.vue'
new Vue({
    el: '#app-vue',
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

### file app.vue

```
<template>
        <gmap-map
                :center="{lat:10, lng:10}"
                :zoom="7"
                map-type-id="terrain"
                style="width: 500px; height: 300px"
        ></gmap-map>
</template>

<script>
import { Map } from 'vue2-google-maps'
export default {
  name: 'app',
    components: {
      'gmap-map': Map
    },
    data () {
        return {
            center: {lat: 10.0, lng: 10.0},
            markers: [{
                position: {lat: 10.0, lng: 10.0}
            }, {
                position: {lat: 11.0, lng: 11.0}
            }]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

but it is not working, the page is empty what am i doing wrong ?

**"vue": "^2.5.2",**

**"vue2-google-maps": "^0.8.4"**

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: I have nothing of error, what do you thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing my dependecies

```
"vue": "2.2.1",
"vue-loader": "11.1.3",
"vue-template-compiler": "2.2.1",
"vue2-google-maps": "0.8.4".
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the autocomplete component and on their doc(vue2-google-maps) the component has a property bounds, do you know the data structure of bounds? How can you pass bounds?